# Xcode10 Validating: No transparencies in my images but still not accepting?

Tags: xcode

Everything was OK on previews versions   and  I am 100% sure that all my images and icons (icon-1024.png included) has no "transparencies" plus has no "alpha channels" also,

Then, I am trying to validate my APK by the menu "Organizer" BUT, getting the same error message:

> Invalid App Store Icon.
>   The App Store Icon in the asset catalog in 'nonono.app' cant be transparent nor contain an alpha channel.

The tools I used to adjust my images:

```
https://appiconmaker.co,
https://makeappicon.com     
and 
mogrify -alpha off res/icon/ios/*.png
```

> and 
>   here a print from my mac:
>   [image]
>
> and 
>   another from xcode:

[image]

What I am doing wrong? I appreciate any tips!
everything was OK on previews versions!!

Thanks.

Comment: This is not taking about random images but specifically the App Store icon. Have you checked that? Also, there are app available that will format your App Store icon correctly for you.

Comment: Yes, my "icon-1024.png" was the first to adjust, to be sure i ve transform all the remain icons,  please, were can I find this "app" to format my apk?

Comment: ohh  that tools...   already done...  no changes...

Comment: please do not see it in this way...  my app is not working and I know that... thats why I need help... I cant see my error...   friends keep telling me to remove that alpha channel..  BUT I ve done that! and all of my apk....  please look at my screen shot... I repet it in many tools... and still nothing.. I am so tired...  I jusr hate this xcode10.

Comment: I just added one shot from myxcodde...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long week, by the help from friends, I finale managed it!

The problem is in the xCode, you have to make sure to remove all the wrong icons first, and then

> create one new empty sheet by [editor][AddAssets][AppIcons&launhccImages][New macOS Generic Icon],

[image]

> and put the correct icon...

[image]

Thanks all for the help,  Kjuly !

Answer (score 5):

I've met this case before, you can try steps below to remove the alpha channel:

1. Open your example.png image with the Preview.app.
2. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> to "save as" the image, you'll get a new copy.
3. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> to save the new copy, in this step, you'll get a setting dialog like screenshot below, just uncheck that "Alpha" checkbox, and save the new copy as your example.png file.

[image]

---

Note: Make sure your uploaded images have no alpha channel in two places below ("App Previews and Screenshots", and "App Store Icon" in General App Information section):

[image]

[image]

---

If you checked and all are fine. One more suggestion: "save as" your image twice (open the image w/ Preview.app, then press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> twice, you'll get a "* copy 2.png" file). Remove that copy's alpha channel and save it.

Cause I just tried this in one of your image, notice the image has a smaller size, which might lead by removing the real alpha channel.

[image]

Comment: thanks Kjuly, done.. once more... but no efects... as I sayed before I am sure those images are "transparencies" and "alphaChannels" free...   and still not vadidating.. on xcode10....

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto I was sure my images have no alpha channel as well when got this error from App Store at that time. I suggest you check all images, including your app review screenshots. Both icon & app review screenshots should not have alpha channel.

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto maybe u can package & upload your icons & screenshots somewhere (those asserts are public, have no sensitive data, right?), i can help to do a quick check for u later.

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto like uploading the package to dropbox or other cloud drive.

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto how about the images u uploaded to http://appstoreconnect.apple.com ? I just checked ur package, those launch images have the alpha channel, icons are fine. But generally, they should be ok cause they're packaged inner app, u need to make sure the review images u uploaded to http://appstoreconnect.apple.com have no alpha channel.

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto great :D

Comment: As i suspect... the problem wasnt by the  .PNGs  but the xcode it self..  how to put a Ansuer to my on question in the SO?

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto well, ur old dirty files contains the alpha channel. lol

Comment: Maybe a xCode cache problem, but I do not care anymore !! just delete then all (template included)  and rebuild!!  rsrsrs  THANKS!!

Comment: Thanks! The alpha thing was the solution for me

Answer (score 0):

I face the same error when uploading the app through Xcode. I resolve this issue by updating my app icon. I built an app using Flutter and I add a transparent icon that was causing the problem. I updated my icons with white background and it worked for me.